# Triangular wave generation using consant current

Tags: constant-current, waveform

I am trying to design a circuit, that will generate a triangular wave from charging/discharging a capacitor with a constant current, but am stuck.

I have a power supply of +-12V and +5V, the circuit will source/sink at maximum 200mA.

I was thinking of building something along this line:

- push-pull stage controlled by something like an op-amp (where the duty cycle can be set),
- comparator one with a sufficiently high hysteresis or two comparators, one for positive and one for negative part

This is just a "pseudo-schematic", of what I was talking about:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiH7ed.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Please note that resistor and capacitor values are not real. And that U3 is this controlling circuit.

So, my question is, if this is a suitable circuit, how would you design "U3 part"? And, if this is not a good circuit, could you show me a correct one.

A description of the operation of your circuit is desirable.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that the frequency and the duty cycle will be setable. Frequency by the resistor and the capacitor. Duty cycle, I dont know yet.

Comment: http://basicelectronicsengineering.blogspot.nl/2013/04/practical-integrator-circuit-triangle.html

Comment: @jippie I am aware of this option, but dont have a square wave to be feed into the integrator. Before you say I can use 555 or uC. The frequency of the triangular wave will be in the order of 100kHzs or even MHz.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can make an RC oscillator with inverted amplifier easily into the 100kHz and MHz range.. so it's not really impossible!